# Building loop for JSON parameter (date) in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

```
import requests
import json
import pprint

    params = {
        "postal_code" : "91941",
        "country" : "US",
        "start_date" : "2020-01-01",
        "end_date" : "2020-01-02",
        "key" : "key"
        }
    
    r = requests.get("https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/history/daily", params)
```

I need to loop through dates in JSON request. I have a free account and I can only get weather data request for one day. Requests for more days (month, year) are paid so I need break it up into multiple requests with different dates. `start_date` and `end_date` should change after every iteration. Any ideas?

Comment: So, you want to generate a sequence of dates that is one day apart? Or, you want to add one day to a date? Those should be trivial problems you can find solutions online, so I'm not really sure what your problem is. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Oh, btw, there is no JSON in your code nor is the `json` module used.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is? It sounds like you just have to create a loop for the start and end date, for which you can use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module, and increase the time with a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I'll respond myself:

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import date, timedelta

startdate = date(2020, 1, 1)
enddate = date(2020, 1, 2)
plusoneday = timedelta(days=1)

for _ in range(3): #time period
    
    params = {
    "postal_code" : "91941",
    "country" : "US",
    "start_date" : startdate,
    "end_date" : enddate,
    "key" : "key"
    }

    r = requests.get("https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/history/daily", params)

    try:
        weather = r.json()
    except:
        print("Invalid JSON or JSON doesn't exist")
    else:
        for record in weather['data']:
            print(record['datetime'], "MIN temp", record['min_temp'], "MAX temp", record['max_temp'])
            
    startdate += plusoneday
    enddate += plusoneday
```

I used datetime module as suggested. I wrote this code just for my weather research purposes so I can change the dates and time period manually. It prints out days and values I was interested in. Thanks for input!